# passing search in react-router and accessing it

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried to pass two values in search while navigating from one page to another .
Here is the code that i used .

```js
this.props.history.push({
                pathname:'/topics',
                search:'?lessonPlanId='+lessonPlanId+'?chapterId='+data._id
            });
```

Now I tried to access that using

```js
let qs = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
          console.log('qs is',qs);
          this.lessonPlanId= qs.id;
```

I get qs as an object

```js
{lessonPlanId: "5b72dc8195a30e11a11a8ed1?chapterId=5b72dfa995a30e11a11a8ed3"}
```

I want to access the lessonPlanId and chapterId out of it.How do i achieve this as I can't do .lessonPlanId and .chapterId ?

Is there a better way to pass so that i can lessonPlanId and chapterId in my object?This solution will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate query params by using &. Change

`search:'?lessonPlanId='+lessonPlanId+'?chapterId='+data._id`

to

`search:'?lessonPlanId='+lessonPlanId+'&chapterId='+data._id`

Comment: Yes, use an `&` instead of `?` for additional params. The usage of [`querystring.stringify`](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options) would be even better.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted